# Using TGT acquired in Java for SSH/Other applications

Tags: java, ssh, single-sign-on, kerberos, gssapi

Currently, I am able to authenticate users in a java application by using JAAS and grabbing the ticket-granting-ticket that is sent from a Windows server running Active Directory.  This is easily done with the `Krb5LoginModule` in java.

Now I would like to run an ssh command from my java application and use my TGT to enable ssh not to ask for password.  I have seen some tutorials ([OpenSSH & Kerberos](http://www.visolve.com/security/ssh_kerberos.php)) for getting ssh to work with kerberos, but they use `kinit` to get their TGT and the ticket is stored in /tmp/krbcc_XXX.  Then after the ticket is generated they can ssh freely.

I could write the TGT to disk and store it in /tmp/krbcc_XXX or I could run the ssh command in a `PrivilegedAction`, however I don't know if either will work.  Is there an accepted way to do this?

Basically, I would like to call something like this and have it not ask me for a password:

```
// Create Command.
List<String> arguments = new ArrayList<String>();
arguments.addAll(Arrays.asList("ssh", "user@host", "xterm"));

// Run SSH command.
ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(arguments).start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clarify first who will initiate the SSH request. Java or the underlying Linux/Unix system. If you go with the latter, this is not cross-platform and not the Java way. You should use a Java SSH impl which supports Keberos. Everything should go smooth. [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) is a pure Java impl with `gss-api-with-mic` support.

On the other hand, you could try to get the private credentials from the `Subject` created with the `LoginContext` and write it to the default CC file location.. After you have done that, try `klist`. If it reads the cc file, you're done. If this does not work, you could examine Sun's [CC reader code](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/krb5/Credentials.java#Credentials.acquireTGTFromCache%28sun.security.krb5.PrincipalName%2Cjava.lang.String%29) and reverse it. Probably, the `sun.security.krb5.internal.ccache.FileCredentialsCache` is the interesting one along with its update and save methods. The task is to have the private subject credentials be compatible with the desired class `sun.security.krb5.internal.ccache.Credentials`.
**Note**: This solution is completely Sun-dependent. I would go for the first approach or you rather run `kinit` first.